# Compact open topology

Tags: general-topology

- Let $X$, $Y$ be topological spaces.  If $K$ is a compact subspace of $X$ and $U$ is an open subset of $Y$, define $[K,U]=\{f\mid f\in C(X,Y) \text{ and } f(K)\subset U\}$. The sets $[K,U]$ form a subbasis for a topology on $C(X,Y)$ that is called the *compact open topology*.
- A *subbasis* $S$ for a topology on $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union equals $X$. The topology generated by the subbasis $S$ is defined to be the collection $T$ of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $S$.

So why the union of $[K,U]$s equals $C(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $K = \emptyset, U = Y$. Then $[K, U] = C(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible definitions of a subbasis: see [Subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase) in Wikipedia for a full discussion. The most frequently used definition does not require that the subbasis covers $X$. The trick is that finite intersection includes intersection indexed by the empty set, which by convention gives $X$.

Comment: I umderstand $[K_1, U_1]\cap[K_2, U_2]$, however, not be able to figure out what's $[K_1, U_1]\cup[K_2, U_2]$.

Comment: Both are subsets of $C(X,Y)$, so this is just the usual intersection and usual union of two subsets.